# Change 3ds max mesh local origin pivot point

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax

I'm developing a 3D videogame in C# with XNA, my problem comes when I load my model done in 3ds max, and I try to rotate a mesh of it, because the pivot point isn't exported so it takes the local origin of the mesh, the point you get when pressing "Reset Pivot" in 3ds max.

What I want to do is to change its point default value, so that my animation gets the correct pivot point, how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Not 100% positive what you mean here. If you're wondering how to move the pivot, you do this by going to the "Hierarchy" tab, and choosing "Affect Pivot Only," and you can then move the pivot using the transform tool.

Comment: yep, but as I said, I can't get the pivot, but the other point. According to my research this may have something to do with the Reset XForm modifier and mesh matrixes

Comment: Does the default pivot location happen to align with the origin in Max (0, 0, 0)? What happens when you move the entire mesh to some other location in Max, then re-export?

Comment: Well, after a more detailed research (and a night sleeping) I realised why its this point taken, and the reason is that I did that mesh using the lathe modifier, so the origin is where the source spline was, and not the centre of the volume. May Reset XForms fix it?

Comment: It's probably worth a try - if that fails I'd try collapsing the modifier stack before exporting to see if you can get it working that way.

Comment: Well, after XForms it was fixed, but there was still a problem as I was switching rotation axis in wrong matrix, so nothing happened. Theres an strange fact that spoils the correct axis naming, so that when I wanna rotate around Y axis, I must call Matrix.CreateRotationZ(...);

Comment: Probably a difference in coordinate systems? I know for example many graphics applications have -Z looking "into" the screen and +Y pointing "up", whereas in 3DS +Z is "up."

Comment: Yep, now i'll have to search how to fix it, but for the moment I'll go on with the game development. thanks for the help! ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as we talked in comments, the way to fix it was to reset transform matrix with the Xforms modifier.

Answer (score 4):

find here a good description of why this problem exists and a script to solve it:
[xna3ds script](http://metlab.cse.msu.edu/xna3ds.html)

Comment: This answer could be made much better by summarizing the content of the linked post, just in case the linked post ever goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix this, make your shape an editable mesh & move every vertex so that the current center is where you want it to be.
Don't forget to move each vertex with respect to the screen space or world space, not local space.